# How to convert interest rate to discount factor

Tags: finance, applications, actuarial-science

I'm studying on Kellison's Theory of Interest and I'm stuck on the exercise 20/a of the 1st chapter.

If the $i=0.1$ then $d = 0.0901$

$d_5=\frac{A_5-A_4}{A_5}$
when I insert $d$ into this equation, I reach to the;

$\frac{  (1/(1-5d))  -  (1/(1-4d))}{1 / (1-5d) }$ which is simplified as $\frac d{1-4d}$.
When I put the $0.0901$ value for $d$, I can't reach to the answer of $\frac1{15}$ with this solution.

But if I insert $i$ instead of $d$, I reach to $\frac i{1+5i}$ then the result is $\frac1{15}$, which is correct.

After this non-resulting work, I wanted to see the cash flow of this example. And I made  a table in excel with $A_0=100$, $i = 0.1$  and $d= 0.0901$. And surprise surprise I couldn't find the same cash flow by using $i$ and $d$. At the 5th period, the simple interest accumulated value is 150, while the one with simple discount is $183.33$ (with the formula $\frac A {1 - nd}$). Actually, after the first period, the cash flow with the discount rate started to get higher than the one with the interest rate.

As a result I really don't understand how $i$ is converted into $d$.

Any help?

Note: Sorry for the messy equation syntax, I don't how to do it here properly.

Comment: Are you sure your cashflow $A_5$, $A_4$ are given in simple instead of compound discount? In the market, interest rates below/above 1 year is quoted in simple/compound conventions. In terms of mathematics, the approximation $exp(-rT) \approx 1 - rT$ is valid only for small $rT$.

Comment: Hmm I'm confused more. Isn't the future value of A is A/(1-dt) with a simple discount rate of d? Is that correct only for below 1 year?

Comment: Could you post the actual question without any interpretation?

Comment: Find d5 if the rate of simple interest is 10%.

Comment: And what is d5?

Comment: d5 is the effective rate of discount in the period 5

Comment: I'm trying to help you here, and I know this stuff inside out, but you seem intent on not being helped. I don't have your book, or your exercises. If I didn't know what d5 was how do I know what period 5 is? And I don't know what A4 is either.

Comment: 1) You wanted me to write the whole question without any interpretation and I did. 2) You asked for what the d5 is and I answered. What's my fault here?

Comment: So the author doesn't define A1,...,A5, d1,..,d5 or i and d?

Comment: There's nothing to be defined after all, these are general concepts about financial mathematics (i,d,A) and what I'm asking is part of a general concept too. The question is just an example. As a result my question is; How can I use the simple discount rate (instead of the simple interest rate) in finding the effective rate of discount?

Comment: Discount instruments in the US are usually quoted on an ACT/360 basis. You pay (1 - discount_rate * t) now for 1 at maturity where t is the year fraction #days/360. So the discount factor is (1 - discount_rate * t). Just equate this to 1/(1 + r * t) where r is the simple rate, assuming same daycount, and solve.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Just to be clear, this terminology is very clear to people who have taken actuarial exams (or taken classes that prepare you for them), so you don't know all of this inside out.  This isn't strictly financial mathematics.  It is more specifically actuarial mathematics.  I knew what d5 was.

Comment: You may also want to give it a try at [StackExchange-Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Graphth well I'm a quant not an actuary. I certainly know how to derive discount factors from market prices though. If no-one is prepared to define A_i and d_i then I can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming the formula $d = \frac{i}{i+1}$ for simple interest when that formula is only valid for compound interest.  Thus, your first step of determining $d = 0.0901$ is incorrect.

To answer your second question, asked in the comment, if $i$ and $d$ are equivalent rates of simple discount, then $1 + it = \frac{1}{1 - dt}$, so just solve for one or the other.  Note, however, that the accumulation function for simple discount is only defined for $0 \leq t < \frac{1}{d}$, so they can only be equivalent over this interval.

We have
$$1 = (1 + it)(1 - dt) = 1 - dt + it - idt^2.$$
Subtracting one from both sides gives
$$-dt + it - idt^2 = 0.$$
Of course, this holds true when $t = 0$, so let's assume $t \neq 0$ and that allows us to divide both sides by $t$.  This gives
$$i - d = idt.$$
You can solve this for $i$ or $d$ easily now.  Note that a constant simple interest rate $i$ will NOT lead to a constant discount rate $d$, which is clear because there is still a $t$ left in our equation.  And, similarly, a constant simple discount rate will not lead to a constant simple interest rate.  These facts are clear even before we solve this because $1 + it$ is linear when $i$ is constant and $\frac{1}{1 - dt}$ is not linear when $d$ is constant.

Comment: Is there any formula of converting i to d (or d to i) if the case is simple interest? Or should I not convert them to each other at all in a simple interest question and use whatever is given?

Comment: @rakha I added that to my answer.  Does this answer your question?  Essentially, I wouldn't do this problem by finding $d$.  It makes the problem much more difficult.

Comment: Ok I got it. In a nutshell, there is no constant simple discount rate for all the periods equivalent to the simple interest rate. Thank you very much.